# how to use both (and) and (or) in xpath

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I am trying to create an xpath with using (and) and (or) both expression together but not getting success.

1. I want to grab prices of products but some prices comes as `.//p/span[@class='currency-value']` while other comes as `.//p/span/span[@class='currency-value']` so I want to use OR exprssion for this
2. And I don't want price where product is for Advertise so I am using `.//span[not(contains(text(),'Ad'))]`

I have tried below xpath but its not working.

`.//p/span[@class='currency-value'] | .//p/span/span[@class='currency-value'] and .//span[not(.='Ad')]`

Comment: Can you link the website so we can test out our `xpath`s?

Comment: this is link of the page where I need Price (if product have two price one discounted and one original I just need discounted price)
https://www.etsy.com/uk/search?q=sports%20shoes&ref=auto1&as_prefix=sports%20shoes

Answer (score 3):

Rather than saying "try XXX" I think it's useful if you understand what's wrong with your current attempts.

```
.//p/span[@class='currency-value'] | .//p/span/span[@class='currency-value'] and .//span[not(.='Ad')]
```

The "|" operator in XPath means "union" - it forms the union of two node-sets. So `//x | //y` selects the union of the nodes selected by `//x` and those selected by `//y`. So far so good. You can simplify the "union" part of your expression to

```
(.//p/span | .//p/span/span)[@class='currency-value']
```

if you want.

The "and" is more problematic. The operands of "and" have to be booleans, whereas in your expression both operands are node-sets. I suspect (though I can't be sure) that your intent is to exclude from the union node-set those nodes that satisfy the predicate `.='Ad'` but without seeing your source data it's not clear how the products and prices relate to each other. Perhaps you intended this:

```
(.//p/span | .//p/span/span)[@class='currency-value'][not(.='Ad')]
```

or perhaps this:

```
(.//p/span | .//p/span/span)[@class='currency-value'][not(..='Ad')]
```

Either way, if I'm right that your intent is to exclude some of the nodes that would otherwise be selected, then an additional predicate is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the page, this CSS selector will work

```
div.hide-lg:not([data-behat-search-results-ads-xl]):not(.prolist-row) p > span.currency-value, div.hide-lg:not([data-behat-search-results-ads-xl]):not(.prolist-row) p > span > span.currency-value
```

Comment: This CSS selector works perfectly as I needed, it select only discounted price in case if product have two price (discounted and original) and also excluding price for Advertise product.  Thanks   (I am still trying to create xpath for same ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Do not overcomplicate with `//p/span`

```
//span[@class='currency-value'][not(.='Ad')]
```

Comment: This Xpath gives me all prices even price for advertice products which I don't want. And reason for using //p/span was because some product have two price one discount and one origianal but I only want discounted price.


this is link of the page where I need Price (if product have two price one discounted and one original I just need discounted price)
https://www.etsy.com/uk/search?q=sports%20shoes&ref=auto1&as_prefix=sports%20shoes

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Combines @Vitaliy's answer with yours:

```
.//p/span[@class='currency-value'][not(.='Ad')] | .//p/span/span[@class='currency-value'][not(.='Ad')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the use of AND and OR in xpath as below:

this is the Page html:

```
<div class="mtlist-tab">
<ul class="wwf-tab-h">
<li class="tab-head">
<li class="tab-head on">
<li class="tab-head">
</ul>
</div>
```

if you are using AND in xpath where the two elements have same class class name then it will return 2 matching elements.

```
//li[@class='tab-head' and @class='tab-head']
```

if you are using AND in xpath where the two elements have different class class name then it will return 0 matching elements.

```
//li[@class='tab-head' and @class='tab-head on']
```

if you are using OR in xpath where the two elements have different class class name then it will return 3 matching elements(according to the HTML).

```
//li[@class='tab-head' OR @class='tab-head on']
```